# DialogFlow follow up triggers empty response

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have a DialogFlow intent follow up that I'm having a hard time with. It's the only follow up to my main intent, and the issue I'm having is that when 
 the `incidents.data` array is empty it doesn't trigger the `conv.ask` statement in the else case and causes DialogFlow to throw an empty speech response error. The code looks something like this:

```
app.intent('metro_timetable - yes', async (conv: any) => {
  const incidents = await serviceIncidents.getIncidents();
  if (incidents.data.length > 0) {
    conv.ask('I have incidents')
  } else {
    conv.ask(
      `I wasn't able to understand your request, could you please say that again?`
    );
  }
});
```

`incidents.data` gets stored in the global scope, and is set deep within 
the `metro_timetable` intent. It stores an incident for the follow up. Because all `yes` responses trigger the follow up I setup an else case so it catches it if someone says `yes` when `metro_timetable` doesn't understand their original request and asks them to repeat it. If `incidents.data` actually has information to share the dialog triggers correctly and `I have incidents` is correctly read to the user.

In DialogFlow it looks something like this. Where am I going wrong here?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description is a little convoluted how `incidents.data` actually gets set, but it sounds possible that instead of it being set to an empty array, it isn't set at all. In this case, I suspect that the following happened:

1. `incidents.data` would be undefined
2. Trying to evaluate `incidents.data.length` would cause an error
3. Since the program crashes, your webhook doesn't return a result. Since you probably didn't set a result in the UI for the intent, an empty result was returned.

You can probably solve this by doing a test such as (for example)

```
incidents && incidents.data && incidents.data.length > 0
```

Your other issue, however, seems to be that you have a Followup Intent set for a scenario where you don't actually want that as the followup. This is one of the reasons you probably shouldn't use Followup Intents but, instead, only set a context when you send a response where that context would make sense, and look for the "Yes" response in the context you define. Then, when `metro_timetable` doesn't understand the request, you don't set the context and you give an error.

To do this, you would remove the automatically generated `metro_timetable-followup` context from the two Intents. You'll create your own context, which I'll name `timetable` for purposes of this example.

In the fulfillment for the `metro_timetable` Intent, if you respond with something that needs confirmation (ie - when "yes" will be something the user says), you would set the `timetable` context with something like

```
conv.contexts.set('timetable',2);
conv.ask('Are you sure?');
```

You can then create an Intent that checks for `timetable` as the Incoming Context and has training phrases that are equivalent to "yes". In that Intent, you'd do what you need to and respond.

Comment: What is the correct way to set up context replies like you mentioned? You're right that it's being triggered when I don't actually want it to, but I'm not sure how to make the word yes behave differently in a follow up question for different parts of an intent.